# OmniAuth + Rails 3 + Cucumber - undefined method `test_mode!' for Devise::OmniAuth:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, omniauth

When I run the command 'cucumber' in my new Rails 3.1 project I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `test_mode!' for Devise::OmniAuth:Module (NoMethodError)
```

here are my gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'turn', '<0.8.3'
  gem 'cucumber', '1.1.4'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'launchy'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'koala'
```

and finally this code from /features/support/env.rb

```
Devise::OmniAuth.test_mode!

Before do
  Devise::OmniAuth.short_circuit_authorizers!
  Devise::OmniAuth.stub!(:facebook) do |b| 
    b.post('/oauth/access_token') do
      [200, {}, { :access_token => 'facebook_access_token' }.to_json]
    end 

    b.get('/me?access_token=facebook_access_token') do
      [   
        200, {}, 
        {   
          :id         => '1111111111',
          :link       => 'http://facebook.com/username',
          :email      => 'username@example.com',
          :first_name => 'User',
          :last_name  => 'Name',
          :website    => 'http://relike.com/users/username'
        }.to_json
      ]   
    end 
  end 
end
```

Does anyone see what's going wrong here?